# How to conditionally compile functions in pallet::call?

Tags: pallet, runtime, features

I'm trying to have my pallet compile a pallet call based on the feature that is set, for example if I have two function calls `feature_one()` and `feature_two()`, it works fine with `feature_one` but when I add the second method with the `#[cfg(feature= "feature2")]` macro it gives me the following error:

```rs
      error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `feature_two` found for struct `pallet::Pallet` in the current scope

    function or associated item not found in `pallet::Pallet<T>`
    help: there is an associated function with a similar name: `feature_one`
```

this is the pallet code:

```rs
        #![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
        #[cfg(test)]
        mod tests;
        pub use pallet::*;
        #[frame_support::pallet]
        pub mod pallet {
            use frame_system::pallet_prelude::*;
            pub use sp_runtime::traits::Extrinsic;
            #[pallet::pallet]
            #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
            pub struct Pallet<T>(_);
        
            #[pallet::config]
            pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
                type Event: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>;
            }
            #[pallet::event]
            #[pallet::generate_deposit(pub(super) fn deposit_event)]
            pub enum Event<T: Config> {
                /// An Event has been validated
                CustomEvent { event_id: T::Hash },
            }
            #[pallet::error]
            pub enum Error<T> {
                AlreadySymbitted,
            }
       #[pallet::storage]
        pub(super) type MyStorage<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, T::Hash, T::BlockNumber>;
    
    
            #[pallet::call]
            impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
                #[cfg(feature= "feature1")]
                #[pallet::weight(0)]
                pub fn feature_one(_origin: OriginFor<T>, event_id: T::Hash) -> DispatchResult {
                } 
    
               #[cfg(feature= "feature2")]
               #[pallet::weight(0)]
                pub fn feature_two(_origin: OriginFor<T>, event_id: T::Hash) -> DispatchResult {
            
            }
    
        }
```

Comment: FYI `#[cfg(feature= "feature1")]` is supported in the `construct_runtime!` macro these days.

Comment: @Squirrel how can i use it? are there any examples? does it solve my problem? any links?

Comment: This was the PR that added the functionality: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11818

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this.

You can do like this, with one feature flag for both alternatives.

```rs
#[pallet::call]
impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
  #[pallet::call_index(0)]
  #[pallet::weight(0)]
  fn f() {
    Self::ff();
  }
}

impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
  #[cfg(not(feature = "g"))]
  fn ff() {}

  #[cfg(feature = "g")]
  fn ff() {}
}
```

or use two independent flags to include a stub when unused:

```rs
#[pallet::call]
impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
  #[pallet::call_index(0)]
  #[pallet::weight(0)]
  fn f() {
     Self::ff();
  }

  #[pallet::call_index(1)]
  #[pallet::weight(0)]
  fn g() {
     Self::gg();
  }
}

impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
  #[cfg(feature = "f")]
  fn ff() {}
  #[cfg(not(feature = "f"))]
  fn ff() { return not enable }

  #[cfg(feature = "g")]
  fn gg() {}
  #[cfg(not(feature = "g"))]
  fn gg() { return not enable }
}
```

or simply hide the struct behind a feature flag:

```rs
#[pallet::call_index(0)]
#[pallet::weight(0)]
fn f(.., params: Params) {
   Self::ff(params);
}

#[cfg(feature = "f")]
struct Params {
  f: u8
}

#[cfg(feature = "g")]
struct Params {
  g: u16
}
```

Comment: what if feature_two() have diffrent paramters than feature one, in this case it wouldn't work in the first solution? and does it work that way? whats wrong with my implementation?

Comment: 1_, 2_ From the code in your question, I saw they are the same. It depends on the code, maybe you can leave the optional field empty. e.g. always passing an empty vec to it. 3_ `#[pallet]` not support `cfg` yet.

Comment: yeah true, but what if they are not the same, i forgot to add that sorry

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: in the first solution, it does not allow duplicate name definitions both are named ff in feature f and feature g

Comment: solution 2 allows to functions to be available at the same time `f()` and `g()` but i want only one function like solution one, also i dont understand what is return not enable?

Comment: If you want 1 feature, go for 1.  If you want 2 features, go for 2.

Comment: I don't know anything about your project. `return not enable` is just pseudo code. Return what, when failure it's totally up to you.

Comment: And, one more thing. I don't recommend you use this. If someone already scheduled a call, you change this feature after the runtime upgrade. The scheduled-mistake call might break your chain.

Comment: i suggested the edit which should solve the duplicate name definition, also what do you mean break my chain? wont the new runtime simply reject the call and move on? and also is it because they have diffrent arguments that the call would break?

Comment: Imagine, `schedule(0x1000000)` means `feature_f(xxx)`. After the runtime upgrade, it was changed to `feature_g(xxx)`. It will try to decode the `0x1000000` into a different call. We don't know what would happen.

Comment: BTW, I'll stop this thread here. You should ask these off-topic things in other questions.

Comment: thank you, learned a lot